# How to move all subdirectories into the parent folder in bash?

Tags: linux, mv

Suppose, I have a parent folder which includes 4 sub-folders. Each of the sub-folders can have a different number of subfolders (let's call them sub-sub-folders). How do I move all sub-sub-folders into the parent folder and delete all sub-folders bash?

For now, I am using the following command:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there, but what your command does is moving **everything below** *depth 2*, so you need to limit the maxdepth as well:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

Since you're *moving* them you don't need to delete anything.

Comment: To remove the now empty sub-folders, the following could be done: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -print -exec rmdir {} +` But this removes all empty dirs, not the original sub-folders only, which would require a two stage moving.